# use jQuery to close many div s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div s :

> manufacturer[1], manufacturer[2], manufacturer[3], ... etc ...

I tried to create a javascritp for loop that close many div , but after a little search I noticed that its impossible.

Close = Hide (display:none)

So i need help with writing a jquery simple code to do that:

```
    function hideAllManufacturers(manufacturersID)
{
    var manufacturer = [1,2,3,];

    $.each(manufacturer, function(index, val) {
        $('.manufacturer['+val+']').hide();
    });


}
```

it does work - but the next of the code after it doesn't been showed. so its probably a problem in what i wrote..

Is it bad that the end i have a comma ?

need your help!

Comment: css visibility:hidden i think may work.

Comment: The comma at the end is a problem in some browsers, you should remove it. But it's not the issue here, the function wouldn't do anything in these browsers. Please show us the "next code"

Comment: @Surinder, c'mon. nonsense.

Comment: its not working it's because of the `[]` in the selector is a metacharacter that must be escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well its because the `[]` is a meta character in CSS selectors that are used by JQuery so you must escape it with two backslashes `\\` so it would be like this

```
$(".manufacturer\\[" + val + "\\]").hide();
```

reference:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

and another thing that doesn't make it work is because of the extra comma in your array

```
var manufacturer = [1,2,3,]; //remove the last comma
```

and it must be like this

```
var manufacturer = [1,2,3];
```

Comment: +1, also you need to point to the extra comma in the array and you'll get another +1 ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a wildcard like so

```
$('[class^="manufacturer"]').hide();
```

That will hide all elements with a class starting with manufacturer, so would hide .manufacturer[1], .manufacturer[2] etc.

This also makes it easier going forward as you will not need to update the manufacturer array in jQuery if you add a new manufacturer at a later date. It will immediately capture the new one with the wildcard saving time and unnecessary code.

Comment: _That will hide all elements with a class containing manufacturer_ That's not quite right. It should be **starting with** instead of **containing**